# How to write test for s3 Upload using aws-sdk-client-mock

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a test using [aws-sdk-client-mock](https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock#lib-storage-upload) and I think I am close. Here is the code.

```
            it('should upload files', async () => {
                const s3Mock = mockClient(S3Client);
                const s3 = new S3Client({});
                const s3Service = new S3FilesService(s3, 'test-bucket');
                s3Mock.on(CreateMultipartUploadCommand).resolves({UploadId: '1'});
                s3Mock.on(UploadPartCommand).resolves({ETag: '1'});

                const s3Upload = new Upload({
                    client: new S3Client({}),
                    params: {
                        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
                        Key: 'test',
                        Body: 'test', // 6 MB
                    },
                });
                const result = s3Upload.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
                    console.log(progress);
                });

                // s3Service.uploadObject is my function that uses lib-storage to upload
                const putObjectResult = await s3Service.uploadObject(
                    'test',
                    'test', // 6 MB
                );

                await s3Upload.done();

                expect(putObjectResult).toEqual(result);
            });
```

However, I am not sure what exactly to assert or expect. My `uploadObject` function returns `return await s3Upload.done();` So I feel like I should be able to expect the 2 to be equal. However, `putObjectResult` is `undefined`.  Can someone help me out here and tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am not sure what exactly to assert or expect

I would assert and expect that `s3Service.uploadObject` has been called one time and has been called with the expected params
https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-
https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would make a difference, but

```js
const s3Upload = new Upload({
  client: s3, // not `new S3Client({})`
  params: {
    Bucket: 'test-bucket',
    Key: 'test',
    Body: 'test', // 6 MB
  },
});
```

may produce better results as the client is set to use the mocked bucket and your upload is not using the same client